# Are “Rad” and “Rat” seriously pronounced in the same way?

Tags: pronunciation, consonant-sounds

Are *Rad* and *Rat* seriously pronounced in the same way? 
I’ve recently read that both *Rad* and *Rat* are pronounced in the same way as /rat/. Basically in both cases the end letter is a /t/.

Is it really like that? Or does it regard only specific areas of Germany/Austria?

Comment: No they are not. One is pronounced with a "d" in the end, the other with a "t".

Comment: @Robert: Please do not use comments for answering. Also, it’s not [that](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rat) [simple](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rad), [to say the very least](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auslautverh%C3%A4rtung#N.C3.B6rdliches_Deutsch).

Comment: Yes, both are pronounced as [ʀaːt] in standard German.

Comment: Ok, so someone says it is the same and someone says it is different. 
In both cases : why?

Comment: Our grammar book in year five noted common spelling mistakes illustrated with comic pictures. One of them was ‘Mit Rad (sic!) und Tat stand der Großwesir dem Kalifen zur Seite’, playing on the pronunciation pun.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.bodowinter.com/papers/winter_rottger_IN_grazer.pdf

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Standard German, a phenomenon called [*terminal devoicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing) (*Auslautverhärtung* in German) affects the pronunciation of word-final (or more generally: morpheme-final) consonants. It leads to the merging of the phoneme pairs *b–p, d–t, w–f, g–k* and /z/–/s/ (a phoneme pair not reflected in orthography). These are typically pronounced as if the unvoiced letter were present. Thus, *Rad* is — in Standard German — pronounced as *Rat* (/rat/).<sup>[1]</sup>

If the final consonant is moved away from the end of the morpheme, for example by adding a syllabic inflection,<sup>[2]</sup> terminal devoicing does not kick in and the voiced sound is spoken. Thus, *Räder* is /​ˈ​rɛ:**d**ɐ/ while *Räte* is /​ˈ​rɛ:**t**ə/.

The morpheme-boundary one is important. If you build a compound word, such as *Radlager*, terminal devoicing still happens. Standard German pronunciation is /​ˈ​rat​ˌ​lagɐ/.

I explicitly said *Standard German* throughout this answer so far (in all cases except for one). This is because terminal devoicing is not prevalent throughout all dialects of Germany, Switzerland, Austria and the other places where German is natively spoken. Rather, it is a feature most present in the North of Germany. Southern speakers<sup>[3]</sup> tend to differentiate between hard and soft final consonants, so that e.g. in Bavaria a difference can be heard between *Rad* and *Rat*.<sup>[4]</sup>

Terminal devoicing is not a feature only present in German. It is also observed in Catalan, Dutch, Russian, Czech, Korean and others. The Scandinavian languages do not feature it, as it developed after the division between continental and North Sea Germanic.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: Some argue that the /a/ in *Rad/Rat* should be long (/ra:t/). I argue that long and short /a/ are more of a phonetic difference than a phonemic one in German.

[2]: Beware with e.g. genitive forms. *Des Rades* is /ˈra**d**əs/ because an additional syllable is introduced. The more common and shorter *des Rads* is /ˈra**t**s/, because the consonant is still part of the morpheme-final consonant cluster.

[3]: *Southern* here is meant as a synonym for *oberdeutsche Dialekte*: Bavarian (*bairisch*) and Alemannian dialects including those spoken in Switzerland, Austria, Alsace, South Tyrol and Liechtenstein. The Franconian dialects (which I consider to be central German, because Franconia is in central Germany) tend to merge the two sounds but much closer to a /d/ sound than a /t/ sound. You may realise that the entire issue is very complicated.

[4]: Phonetically, one may argue that a final *d* may still be a tad harder than initial or medial *d* but the difference is less than the difference between *d* and *t*.

Comment: This might be more suitable for a separate question, but does terminal devoicing affect the vowel at all? I'm thinking of the difference between the vowels in English "write" and "ride".

Comment: @chepner Nope, it doesn’t.

Comment: I have come across several papers that describe the idea of "incomplete neutralization," where even though devoicing occurs, their are still some phonetic differences on average between words ending in a devoiced lenis consonant and words ending in a fortis consonant. For example: http://www.bodowinter.com/papers/winter_rottger_IN_grazer.pdf Do you know anything about this? Is it possibly due to influence from the non-devoicing dialects you mention?

Comment: I’m quite convinced there is a phonemic difference between long and short /a/ in _Ratte_ vs. _Rate_.

Comment: @sumelic That’s a very interesting article and unfortunately I don’t know anything about this. One quote sticks out, though: Most speakers perceived no difference while they produced a difference, meaning that even I would have a hard time differentiating incompletely neutralised /d/ from /t/ when listening to someone whose speech includes full terminal devoicing.

Comment: Born and raised in Nürnberg (in the heart of Franconia) I'm pretty sure that the complete opposite of what you wrote about southern speakers is true - here *Rad* and *Rat* are both pronounced like *Rad*. There is little to no difference between hard an soft consonants here.

Comment: @chirlu: Absolutely right - but note that there's no voiced consonant in your example. Rather, it is a classic example of what double consonants are for in German: they show that the **preceding vowel** is short. (Pronounciation of a consonant is usually not affected by doubling it.)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar As a proper Bavarian (sorry, couldn’t resist ;p) I must say that the word *Rat* ends in a decidedly stronger sound than *Rad* does. However, I also know that in Franconia these sounds tend to fall together closer to *d*. Maybe I should add that …

Comment: @Jan I always thought that proper Bavarians never say *Rad* at all, but *Radl* instead ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar True for the bicycle, not necessarily true for the wheel e.g. of the car ;)

Comment: I'm from Austria. It's really weird to us Austrians that it's pronounced that way in Germany.

Answer (score 6):

They both end with the same /t/ sound, that's true. However, to my perception, *Rat* tends to be pronounced with a significantly longer *a* than *Rad*. So basically

- Rad /ʁat/
- Rat /ʁa:t/

This is at least the case in more western standard German (Rhine/Ruhr) in compounds like Stadtrat /'ʃtatʁa:t/ vs Fahrrad /'faʁat/.

The longer a-sound has the effect that the t-t in Rat stands out more than the d-t in Rad, hence it can indeed appear as a bit harder, even if the consonant itself is exactly the same.

Comment: To me, the vowel in Rat must be long, while I would accept both a long or a short vowel in Rad.

Comment: Welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Very nice first answer! As you have some ten thousand rep on SO, pointing you to the [tour] and [help] is probably superfluous, but I’ll do so anyway because traditions ;)